# How to Kill or Blocked request ID after use it by user in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csharpcodeprovider

I have one page that contains a test for Microsoft Office for everyone.
every once must to pay to do the test.
student or someone need to has a request ID like 'v6c5th8lkfG'. 
Request id will send it by email or SMS messages.

I need to block or kill request id after the user has used it

result:
request id 'v6c5th8lkfG' will be (useless) after used it,cannot use it again.

How do I do it in aspnet/c# ?

thanks.

Comment: Well, when you generate the ID, store it in the database. When somebody tries to use an ID, check if it's present in the database. If so, remove it and authorize the request. If not, return an error

Comment: I'll try 
thank you for your post